# How to resolve "no cgroup mount found in mountinfo: unknown" error?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, centos, cgroups

I am getting following error while starting docker container.

```
 Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:326: applying cgroup configuration for process caused: no cgroup mount found in mountinfo: unknown
    Error: failed to start containers: postgres-11

My docker version is ----> Docker version 19.03.13-ce, build 4484c46
OS--> 
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What steps/command you executed which lead to this error?

Comment: I'm trying to start my container by running----> docker start "Container-name", I also tried to run New conatiner by "docker run " CMD..but i got same issue...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, "`OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:340: applying cgroup configuration for process caused: no cgroup mount found in mountinfo: unknown`"

First, check if "`docker run hello-world`" is working properly. This will validate the docker installation.

I found this script very useful.
Owner: https://mobyproject.org/

- Download with "curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker/master/contrib/check-config.sh > check-config.sh"
- Make rwx with "chmod 777 check-config.sh" & execute "./check-config.sh"
- Understand the output, mainly the cgroup hierarchy.
- If cgroup hierarchy is "properly mounted [/sys/fs/cgroup]" then we shouldn't be seeing this problem.
- If cgroup hierarchy is something like "**?????????**" then below are the things which you should seek to fix the problem.

Try & Hit solutions:

1. Install cgroup-utils & cgroup-lite
   `sudo apt-get install cgroup-lite cgroup-utils`
2. https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/219#issuecomment-375160449
   Which is to mount systemd with `sudo mount -t cgroup -o none,name=systemd cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd`
3. There are few kernel setting solutions on the internet that you could try if you like.
4. If nothings works, then it is surely the problem of your docker installation, ***which was my case too [SOLVED]***, then you should go for replacing the docker installation. Default installation with docker-ce version 20.10 was also problematic for me but custom installation of docker-ce version 18.09 was helpful.
   **Remove current installation**: 
    `sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io || sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker || sudo rm -rf /var/lib/containerd`
   **Install new docker-ce, docker-cli & containerd-io as per the Linux distribution**: 
   Go to https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/, choose your Ubuntu version, then browse to pool/stable/, choose amd64, armhf, or arm64, and download the .deb file for the Docker Engine version you want to install & install with `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb`

In the end, recheck `docker run hello-world`.

Comment: Same error in raspberry pi 4. Uninstall, Reboot and Install fixed it.